# wso 2 API manager: how to configure multiple user store

Tags: wso2

I follow the guide: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Multiple+User+Stores
and add new UserStoreManager,but it issue exception and can not work

```
[2013-08-07 23:59:33,668] INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
   [2013-08-07 23:59:33,715] INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent
   Client [2013-08-07 23:59:37,910] ERROR - DatabaseUtil Table "UM_ROLE"
   not found; SQL statement: SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE
   UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=? [42102-140]
   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "UM_ROLE" not found; SQL
   statement: SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND
   UM_TENANT_ID=? [42102-140] at
   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167) at
   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144) ...
```

========================================================================

Anybody know how to correct configure it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have defined multiple JDBC user stores,by following the wiki doc[1]. If,yes,then in each UserStoreManager configuration of user-mgt.xml,hope you have define the datasource property as below.

jdbc/WSO2UM2

Can you confirm,the in each defined database,you have populate the user-management related db scripts to populate required db tables for user-manager functionalities,which can be found from "{AM_Home}/dbscripts"? As per logs,it seems the required database tables for user-management haven't populated in one of datasource pointed from one UserStoreManager configuration.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Multiple+User+Stores

Thanks;

Comment: I not run the db script for new user store. 
New question is how to populate the user-management related db scripts?

Comment: First you need to define the datasources which you used as multiple JDBC user stores in master-datasources.xml in {AM_Home}/repository/conf/datasources folder. Then create the respective database in your relational database[in h2/mysql/etc] .And populate the relevant script which can be found from {AM_Home}/dbscripts against newly created above databases.

Comment: OK,use h2-1.2.140-wso2v3.jar and h2.sql under dbscripts, i create corresponding user store database and tables, and api manager startup correctly.

Comment: But in the publisher, if we add new api under secondary user store, the visibility only public, Restricted by Roles, no "Restricted by Roles", and the roles, there are multiple admin and everyone.

Is there other configurations I missed?